# JCommander validate list item

Tags: validation, listitem, jcommander

I'm using JCommander v. 1.72 and my aim is to get a (comma-seperated) list of strings in a parameter and validate the single strings. Sounds simple, right?

Here is my code:

```
@Parameter(names = { "-sort", "-s" }, validateWith = ParameterValidatorHeader.class)
private List<String> sort = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I run the programm with this command:

```
-sort column1,column2
```

I expected that JCommander would call the validator **after** splitting on the single items, i.e. validate "column1", validate "column2".
But obviously the string "column1,column2" is sent to the validator class before splitting the parameter value.

How can I achieve to do the validation on the single items instead?
(Sure, I could do the validation with pure Java **after** parsing them with JCommander...)

Thanks
Erich

Answer (score -1):

You can't, not by using JCommander at least, the docs are quite clear on that

[4.2 Global parameter validation](http://jcommander.org/#_global_parameter_validation)

> After parsing your parameters with JCommander, you might want to perform additional validation across these parameters, such as making sure that two mutually exclusive parameters are not both specified. **Because of all the potential combinations involved in such validation, JCommander does not provide any annotation-based solution to perform this validation because such an approach would necessarily be very limited by the very nature of Java annotations.** Instead, you should simply perform this validation in Java on all the arguments that JCommander just parsed.